# Counting number of Boolean switches in R

Tags: r

With the array:

```
my_array <- c(F,T,T,F,F,T,T,T,F,T,F)
```

I need a script that will tell me how many times the value went from False to True. Just by eye it's easy to see it did that 3 times.  I'm only interested on it switching from False to True and NOT from True to False.

Comment: You really should write `my_array <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)`. See what happens with `T = -3` and `F = 10`. Or even worse, with `T = FALSE` and `F = TRUE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you care only about the times when it went from FALSE to TRUE, this is the number of times the `diff` of the vector is equal to 1:

```
sum(diff(my_array) == 1)
# [1] 3
```

This is in my opinion the most direct way to address your question, but note that R also has the excellent `rle` function that returns the run-length encoding of your vector, namely the length of each section of consecutive values within the vector. You could use `rle` to address your particular query by counting the number of runs (excluding the last) that take the FALSE value:

```
sum(head(rle(my_array)$values, -1) == FALSE)
# [1] 3
```

Note that both of these solutions took advantage of the fact that this is a vector with only TRUE/FALSE values. A general approach to count the number of transitions from some value A to some value B is to compare `head(vector, -1)` with `tail(vector, -1)` -- namely all but the last element of the vector against all but the first. In your case:

```
sum(head(my_array, -1) == FALSE & tail(my_array, -1) == TRUE)
# [1] 3
```

The first element of `head(my_array, -1) == FALSE` indicates whether the first element of `my_array` is FALSE, the second element is whether the second element is FALSE, and so on. Meanwhile, the first element of `tail(my_array, -1) == TRUE` indicates whether the **second** element of `my_array` is TRUE, the second element indicates whether the **third** element is TRUE, and so on. Therefore, the corresponding elements of `head(my_array, -1)` and `tail(my_array, -1)` are one apart and enable us to check conditions on pairs of elements.

Comment: The third line of code you provided is great and what I was looking for.  The data I'm working with is 300,000+ lines and sometimes values other than True or False get thrown in.  Do you have a link that explains better why and how that line works, or could you explain it more in depth yourself?

Comment: @ChaseGrimm I've added some explanation of how this works.